# Is there a way to write on a SSD, such that if it is disconnected during the writing process, no data is lost?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I have a Python script that records motion from a camera on an external SSD. There are great chances that the computer (a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org)) receives an impact and gets disconnected from the drive (or even from it's power supply, but that's another topic right?), but I would like to loose no data when that occurs. Is it achievable?

I have read that only the last write cycle is lost when a drive isn't ejected safely. What exactly is a write cycle and how can I potentially use it to accomplish what I want? Maybe I could write chunks of 5 seconds (have write cycles of 5 seconds), so that if the SSD gets disconnected, only 5 seconds are lost, what do you think?

How would that apply in terms of code?

Right now I am using the [Picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/) library and it uses file streams. If the SSD gets disconnected, there is not enough time to `close()` the stream, is that why the data gets lost? In my tests, when I disconnect the SSD, I only seem to get the first 2-3 seconds of the video, whether the sequence I am recording is 1 minute or 15 seconds long.

Right after disconnecting the SSD, I normally get some kernel error messages in the console (Linux):

```
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Nov 12 01:43:41 ...
 kernel:[  138.263099] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Nov 12 01:43:41 ...
 kernel:[  138.366239] Process vc.ril.video_en (pid: 2403, stack limit = 0xb47c0210)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Nov 12 01:43:41 ...
 kernel:[  138.374211] Stack: (0xb47c1c80 to 0xb47c2000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Nov 12 01:43:41 ...\
 kernel:[  138.379835] 1c80: 00000000 b5b84ce0 807fd650 b667536c a0000013 00000000 b47c1ccc b47c1ca8\

...
```

which freezes everything up in this console session.

Sometimes, but more rarely (about 1/10 times), the kernel does not give an error, but the script raises an exception (`IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error`) and shows a stack trace in the console.

Any insight is appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Unless you planned on storing the data in memory before it was written to hard disk, the answer is likely "no".  But that also depends on how much memory your system has and what file encoding you're using.

Comment: When you say "Unless you planned on storing the data in memory before it was written to hard disk", do you mean keeping the data until the SSD is plugged back into the computer? The system has 1GB of RAM and the file encoding is H264. The videos are recorded in 1080p30 though, so the space would fill up quickly, although it could be a solution.

Comment: Calling fsync() or sync() periodically will force data to be written to disk.  Any write() calls before a fsync() or sync() will be sent to the disk before the sync call returns.  There will be a performance hit, potentially a very large one.

Comment: You can't fix hardware problems in software. In this particular case, it is difficult to even mitigate the loss. Tighten up the hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did to ensure that only a very small amount of data is lost.

1. Switch off the buffering mode of the file object by passing 0 to the `buffering` argument of the `open` method (only works when opening files in binary mode. e.g. `open(fileName, 'wb+', 0)`). You can also call `flush` manually to empty the file buffer after a `write`.
2. As pointed by @Evan, periodically call `sync` or `fsync` to force the data to be written to disk. Any write() calls before a fsync() or sync() will be sent to the disk before the sync call returns. There will be a performance hit, potentially a very large one.

Answer (score 0):

When your application calls "write()", Linux doesn't actually write to the disk. (If it did, everything would be very slow.)

The reason is that disks are very slow at "seeking" (moving around the disk), but very fast at "streaming" (writing data sequentially). So Linux will buffer data in memory, then write it all out in large sequential chunks.

By default, Linux will keep data in memory for up to 30 seconds before it's written out. If that is too big for you, you can tune it. Try `echo 500 > /proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centiseconds` to try and write out data every 5 seconds.

See:
http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/linux-pdflush.htm
https://lonesysadmin.net/2013/12/22/better-linux-disk-caching-performance-vm-dirty_ratio/

Comment: If Linux keeps 30 seconds of data in memory, how come I only get a 2-3 seconds clip when I write on disk for 1 minute? Shouldn't I be getting a 30 seconds clip? And also, why am I getting a 2-3 seconds clip if I write on disk for 20 secs?

Comment: Maybe the reason why I get 2-3 seconds clips when recording for 15 seconds is because the Picamera calls `fsync` at the beginning. And maybe the reason I get 2-3 seconds clips when recording for 1 minute, is that I do not call `flush`, which leaves the data in the Python buffer, not allowing it to be handled by the OS.